# Re-use the same engine for different databases on the same server?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Sqlalchemy creates a new connection whenever you call `create_engine`. If you have multiple databases on the same instance, this gets tricky because Postgres can only support so many active connections.

I have a topology where my backend needs to access different databases on the same database instance. That id for a Postgres URI `postgresql://[ userspec @][ hostspec ][/ dbname ]`, `userspec` and `hostspec` are always the same but `dbname` can change. I'd like for Sqlalchemy to re-use the same engine connection since it's hitting the same host even if it's going to different databases. Any ideas?

Comment: A connection is to a database not to host, so you will need to specify a new connection for each database. As to multiple connections: 1) Don't hold connections any longer then needed 2) Explore [connection pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html)

Comment: Why? I understand you're looking for optimisation, but there's nothing to re-use. Other RDBMS might offer mid-session db switches (like MySQL `use database`),PostgreSQL doesn't. Pooling suggested above can save you some time opening and closing connections. If you're not using anything actually requiring an exclusive connection for the entire operation (autocommit off, temp objects with re-used names, locks, session settings), you can share/re-use the same pre-established connections to each db, with or without a pool, without closing and re-opening them each time.

Comment: To be clear in MySQL `database = schema` per [Glossary Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/glossary.html#glos_schema): *In MySQL, physically, a schema is synonymous with a database. You can substitute the keyword SCHEMA instead of DATABASE in MySQL SQL syntax,...*. You are not actually switching databases, you are switching schemas which is also possible in Postgres.

Comment: "Sqlalchemy creates a new connection whenever you call create_engine" -> no it does not. By default it will create a connection pool, but it won't start actually creating connections until you actual execute a statement.  You can configure the pool size or use a `NullPool` if you don't want a pool.

Answer (score 1):

> Sqlalchemy creates a new connection whenever you call `create_engine`.

Not really. As @snakecharmerb mentions in a comment to the question, `create_engine()` creates a *connection pool* but no actual connections are created until they are needed, e.g., by calling `.execute()`, `.execute_driver_sql()`, or similar.

> I'd like for Sqlalchemy to re-use the same engine connection since it's hitting the same host even if it's going to different databases.

That's not a particularly good idea. An `Engine` is more than just a connection (or pool of connections), and the expectation is that the engine is associated with a particular database. If you want to limit the number of actual database (DBAPI) connections to the server while maintaining separate engines for each database, you can

#### Take care when managing SQLAlchemy connections

In particular, use a context manager to ensure that the connection is released back to the pool when you are done with it.

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(…)
# conn is released back to the pool when the context manager exits
```

#### Limit the size of each connection pool

Limiting the size of the connection pools will help prevent your app from using up all of the server connections, and will help identify situations where your app might be leaking connections (if you exhaust the pool).

#### Periodically close inactive connections

```py
engine.pool.dispose()
```

will close any checked-in database connections in the pool. That won't help if your app is leaking connections, but it will prevent idle connections from "sitting around" on the server.